# AsyncTask Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I know that previous execution of AsyncTask is running - my question is how do I finish it and re-execute , because my parameters for it has been changed.

```
    protected class ImageDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Response, Void, Void>{

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                poolTasks.add(this);
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Response... params) {
                int count=params[0].getGetPosts().getPostsCount();
                for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                    Post post = params[0].getGetPosts().getPosts(i);

                    if(!isCancelled()){
                        try {

//some code to download images
} catch (Exception e) {


                        }
                        publishProgress();
                    } else poolTasks.remove(this);
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                poolTasks.remove(this);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onCancelled() {
                super.onCancelled();
                poolTasks.remove(this);
            }
        }
```

now on parameters update that's how I call this task :

```
     Log.d("MyLog"," imageTask.getStatus()="+imageTask.getStatus());
     if (imageTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){
         imageTask.cancel(true);
     }
     imageTask.execute(response);
```

first, ths status, judging by the Log is FINISHED. so how could it be running? and how do I restart this AsyncTask properly?

Answer (score 0):

From personal experience, an AsyncTask instance is only good for one execution. It isn't reusable. For your purpose, you should re-initialize it and then execute.

Hope I could help.

For reference, look for heading 'Threading rules' [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: I use it in a static method so I need this as a static object . I can't do just new ImageTask.execute(response); - I need to declare it as static first

Comment: Can't you use a variable as follows?

`static ImageTask newInstance = new ImageTask( /* params */ );
newInstance.execute( /* params */ );`

or

`ParentClass.staticInstance = new ImageTask( /* params */ );
ParentClass.staticInstance.execute ( /* params /* );`

Please share the declaration code, so I can understand better.

Comment: I use it like that - it's  protected static ImageDownloadTask imageTask; in declaration and imageTask=new ImageDownloadTask(); in onCreate();

Comment: From my limited understanding, you could create a function in the declaration scope to reinit `imageTask`. Otherwise, I suggest you either make it accessible and modifiable in the scope or use a locally declared instance. `AsyncTask`s aren't reusable, pal. :)